# Loading in script tag from seperate php file does not work

Tags: javascript, php, html

Part of Main php-file:

```
    <script>
        let current_effect;

        function getRandomEffect() {
            let effect;
            do {
                effect = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
            } while (effect === current_effect);
            return effect;
        }

        function updateEffectContainer(effect) {
            // Construct the filename of the PHP file for the specified effect
            const filename = 'effect' + effect + '.php';

            // Load the HTML content from the PHP file using AJAX
            fetch(filename)
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(html => {
                    // Update the effect container with the HTML content
                    document.getElementById("effect-container").innerHTML = html;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                });
        }

        document.getElementById("changeEffectButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
            current_effect = getRandomEffect();
            updateEffectContainer(current_effect);
        });

        current_effect = getRandomEffect();
        updateEffectContainer(current_effect);
    </script>
```

effect0.php:

```
<p>test</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(test-alert);
</script>
```

The main PHP file selects an effect [0||1||2] when the site is loaded and when the "changeEffectButton" button is pressed. I can see "test" being displayed (in the case that effect0.php is chosen), but no alert window pops up.

Any idea why and how to fix it?

Thanks for every input! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this to print from PHP using js

```
<script>
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "example.php";
    var method = "GET";
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "text";
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var outputDiv = document.getElementById("effect-container");
                outputDiv.innerHTML = xhr.response;
                // Evaluate the script
                eval(outputDiv.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].innerHTML);
            } else {
                console.log("Error: " + xhr.status);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
</script>
```

in example.php you can have,

```
echo '<p>this is printable script</p>';
```

In your case this is the code,

```
function updateEffectContainer(effect) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url = 'effect' + effect + '.php';

        var method = "GET";
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
        xhr.responseType = "text";
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    var outputDiv = document.getElementById("effect-container");
                    outputDiv.innerHTML = xhr.response;
                    // Evaluate the script
                    eval(outputDiv.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].innerHTML);
                } else {
                    console.log("Error: " + xhr.status);
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
```

And PHP is,

```
echo '<p>test</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("test-alert");
</script>';
```